# Jquery Uploadify plugin in zend

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-plugins, flash, uploadify

I am using uploadify plugin to upload images. The main code is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/uploadify-v3.1/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/uploadify-v3.1/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'auto'     : false,
         'buttonCursor' : 'arrow',
        'checkExisting' : '/js/uploadify-v3.1/check-exists.php',
        'fileObjName' : 'the_files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
        'method'   : 'post',
        'queueID'  : 'some_file_queue',
        'swf'      : '/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf',
        //'uploader' : '/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.php',
        'uploader' : 'UploadifyController.php',
        'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
        } ,
    'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
    } 

        // Your options here
    });
});
</script>
```

I have put these code in /views/scripts/.

How can I specify the uploadify.php as UploadifyController.php? or How can I use uploadify in zend?

Also I would like to know about how to specify the path 'upload' as target folder?
Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uploader` options is basically the path of the PHP that will process the upload. Obviously you cannot point to UploadifyController.php because the controller file itself does not execute anything in Zend. Assuming that there is an `processAction` function in that controller, you should use something like:

```
'uploader' : <?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'uploadify', 'action' => 'process'), default, true) ?>
```

Once in the action you can receive the file and save it anywhere using `move_uploaded_file` or relevant Zend framework methods.